# ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) package for gazebo 7.4.0?

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand there are several bugs in 7.0.0 (for instance [this one](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1837/vmware-rendering-z-ordering-appears-random)) which hve been fixed in later versions like 7.4.0 and 7.5.0. Are there any PPA's which include a prebuilt version of 7.4.0 or do I need to build from source? Thanks,

philip

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259989/ubuntu-16.04-(xenial)-package-for-gazebo-7.4.0?/) by [hahnpv](https://answers.ros.org/users/30126/hahnpv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running 16.04 (in VMWare, even) and the installed version of Gazebo is 7.5:

```
$ dpkg-query -W | grep gazebo
gazebo7 7.5.0-1~xenial
```

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hahnpv](https://answers.ros.org/users/30126/hahnpv/) on 2017-04-23**:
Interesting. Mine shows

```
$ dpkg-query -W | grep gazebo
gazebo7 7.0.0+dfsg-2

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2
```

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-23**:
What does `apt-cache madison gazebo7` show? (Interestingly, running that just now to test it showed me that I have a pending upgrade to Gazebo 7.6 waiting). Have you previously pinned Gazebo to version 7.0.0?

**Comment by [hahnpv](https://answers.ros.org/users/30126/hahnpv/) on 2017-04-23**:
I have not pinned versions of anything on my system.

```
$ apt-cache madison gazebo7
gazebo7 | 7.0.0+dfsg-2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
gazebo | 7.0.0+dfsg-2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources
```

**Comment by [hahnpv](https://answers.ros.org/users/30126/hahnpv/) on 2017-04-23**:
This appears to agree with http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/gazebo
"Source Package: gazebo (7.0.0+dfsg-2) [universe]"

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-23**:
I can see the problem now. My 7.6 package is coming from the OSRF repository. See the "alternative installation" instructions on this page: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu

**Comment by [hahnpv](https://answers.ros.org/users/30126/hahnpv/) on 2017-04-23**:
Excellent. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually I do update to the latest 7.x version when installing 16.04+Kinetic.
I do that by adding repositories and key as described in [Install Gazebo using Ubuntu packages](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install)
.

Summary of the commands used:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

After that I get `gazebo7 7.14.0-1~xenial` (as for October 2018).

---

Originally posted by [yossi_ov](https://answers.ros.org/users/31601/yossi_ov/) with karma: 78 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2